# Selecting only the first highest value for one entry in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

Here's my Data

```
Column       IV         Source
RRD          5.795765   Personal_Demographics
RRD          5.795765   Cust360_Agreement
RRD          5.792729   External_Data
WO           4.361066   Cust360_Asset
Rating       3.600918   Personal_Demographics
```

My Expected Result

```
Column       IV         Source
RRD          5.795765   Personal_Demographics
WODate       4.361066   Cust360_Asset
Rating       3.600918   Personal_Demographics
```

What I try

```
inds = df.groupby(['Column'])['IV'].transform(max) == df['IV']
```

But the the result

```
Column       IV         Source
RRD          5.795765   Personal_Demographics
RRD          5.795765   Cust360_Agreement
WO           4.361066   Cust360_Asset
Rating       3.600918   Personal_Demographics
```

The first one is have similar value, but I need only one output like

```
Column       IV         Source
RRD          5.795765   Personal_Demographics
WO           4.361066   Cust360_Asset
Rating       3.600918   Personal_Demographics
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `drop_duplicates` + `sort_values`

```
out = df.sort_values('IV',ascending=False).drop_duplicates('Column')
Out[121]: 
   Column        IV                 Source
0     RRD  5.795765  Personal_Demographics
3      WO  4.361066          Cust360_Asset
4  Rating  3.600918  Personal_Demographics
```

If you would like `groupby`

```
df.sort_values('IV',ascending=False).groupby(['Column']).head(1)
```

Comment: Just know that .drop_duplicates can work on one columns only, thanks